# Removing points from a three.js json file

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, data-processing

I have a three.js json model file exported using BufferGeometry from blender plus its texture file.

The object has some noise on it that I'm looking to clean up by processing the json file itself post export (I need to remove some vertices but this is not a smoothing or decimation operation i.e. it's easier to do it with the json data than somewhere else for this work).

So, I have two/three questions when working with the file from a data point of view.

1. What else would I need to do to the file aside from remove point data? I presume corresponding UV's and normals should go? But what about indexes?
2. Rather than removing points from the list could they be set to null? To give the indexes something to map to even if there is no data there?
3. Presuming I can't get away with 2. and therefore remove data from each array consistently in the json file, is there a way to re-compute the indices without going back to blender or similar? Do I need to do this - could I just remove the index array altogether?

I should add, this point removal is currently being done server-side (python currently) not in the browser, but potentially it could be done in the browser if that's a better way to tackle this. Also the model is fairly large at around 250k verticies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current way of removing the vertices (on the server) is the correct way, especially if it handles re-indexing.

1. For every vertex item, you must not only remove its associated attributes (normals, UVs), but yes, your indexing will need updated, and potentially drastically. Consider a shared vertex among several triangles. How are you going to account for that? That sounds like a much harder problem than I'd want to tackle in the browser.
2. No. The vertex list must be populated with values. If you don't want your method to be fully destructive, you could always adjust your indexing to ignore the vertices you don't want, but again, that's not a small task.
3. There are three draw modes: `THREE.TrianglesDrawMode`, `THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode`, and `THREE.TriangleFanDrawMode`. For shared vertices in `THREE.TrianglesDrawMode`, you need indexing. To remove indexing, you would need to define every triangle as a discrete triplet of vertices (potentially LOTS of duplicate data). For `THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode` and `THREE.TriangleFanDrawMode`, some vertices are shared, but the order in which they're in the buffer is critical. Setting up your geometry to do this would be just as hard as refactoring the indices.

I need to ask though: Why don't you try to adjust the noisy vertices, rather than removing them? That's a much simpler task, with much easier math, and you wouldn't need worry about re-indexing.

Comment: To answer your question there's a couple of things being tackled here noise reduction and complete removal of parts of the model which are considered irrelevant (as the model is complex and generated by another system). 

All things considered it was quicker and easier overall to script this via Blender than it was to recompute everything manually working on just the raw threejs data. 

It was nice to try it in on the three data alone but Blender was overall the best/quickest option for us, and the python work already completed was easily transferable back up into blender.